# Is using rsync safe to source files if they being updated?

Tags: files, rsync, corruption

I'm trying to determine if rsync can possibly corrupt source data during a copy.

I understand that the if the source file is being modified, deleted, renamed, etc, rsync may produce a corrupted destination file.

Is it possible that if the source file is being modified by another process (text file to which data is being added, for example).  Is it possible rsync could change and/or corrupt the source file?

I looked at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90245/is-using-rsync-while-source-is-being-updated-safe.) answer on stack but it mainly talks about the possibly of destination corruption.

Comment: I know that's not what you are asking, but did you consider using a code management solution that is designed for this purpose (and offers many other benefits) instead of caring how to make another tool safe for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` NEVER writes to, or modifies, the source file in any way.

- It will delete the source file after a *successful and verified copy* if you specify the `--remove-source-files` flag. (Specifically, this will fail safely and not delete the source file if it is modified during the copy.)
- The filesystem may update the *last access* timestamp on the source file if it is configured to do so